# Convert string "02-04-20189.45" into datetime type in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, datetime

I tried too hard but couldn't do

```
string column - "**02-04-20189.45**"
format = **day-month-yearhour(24).minutes**
to **datetime** type
```

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: Can you please give more information and can you show us what have you done?

Comment: i tried format = "%d-%m-%Y%-H"

Comment: Please update the code to be *real* code (without *)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Sample Dataframe***

```
             date
0  02-04-20189.45
```

Use the **`format`** parameter with **`to_datetime`**:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%d-%m-%Y%H.%M')

0   2018-04-02 09:45:00
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datetime.strptime` with a specified format:

```
from datetime import datetime

x = '02-04-20189.45'

res = datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y%H.%M')

# 2018-04-02 09:45:00
```

[Python's strftime directives](http://strftime.org/) is a useful reference for deriving the appropriate format string. You can also use the above format with `pandas.to_datetime`, although this uses `dateutil.parser`.